# Office.js Excel: Get and Write to Visible Cells

Tags: office-js, excel-2016

I have a simple Office.js app that reads data from a single column, looks up something, and then outputs results to the adjacent column. It works fine under normal conditions, but **if the table is filtered, it ignores the filtering and still looks up everything.**

I've come across .getVisibleView() which correctly gives me just the filtered/visible values:

```
const range = context.workbook.getSelectedRange().getUsedRange().getVisibleView();
range.load("values");
```

but after that, **how can I write to the appropriate 
 corresponding cells?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like you would on a normal range.

```
var visibleRange = context.workbook.getSelectedRange().getUsedRange()..getVisibleView();
visibleRange.values = rangeValuesToSetVisible;
```

-Philip, Developer on the Office Extensibility team